# css gradient background with color behind it

Tags: css, button, gradient

I saw this css button demo that uses a png for gradient overlay https://zurb.com/blog/super-awesome-buttons-with-css3-and-rgba

The benefit of the png gradient is that you can easily change the color of the button or the gradient separately.

It seems like there would be a way to do this with CSS. Have a white gradient background and a separate solid color background behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you are supporting (see support in the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility)), you can do this with a `linear-gradient` as part of the background, e.g.

```css
.awesome_button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  
  background: #444499 linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%);

  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="awesome_button">
  Test Button
</button>
```